# Importing subset of columns from RDBMS to Hive table with Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

Suppose we have mysql database called `lastdb` with table `person`. This table contains 4 columns called: `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `age`.

Rows inside `person` table:

`1, Firstname, Lastname, 20`

I want to import data from this mysql `person` table to hive table with the same structure but only from the first and the last column from table `person`. So after my import the rows in hive table should look like this:

`1, NULL, NULL, 20`

I tried this sqoop command:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lastdb --table person --username root --password pass --hive-import --hive-database lastdb --hive-table person --columns id,age`

But it imports rows to hive table in this format:
`1, 20, NULL, NULL`

Could anyone tell me how to fix that?

Comment: why do you care so much about the order of the column?

Answer (score -1):

Given that rows inside your MySQL table are `id, firstname, lastname, age` of values: `1, NULL, NULL, 20,` then, running the sqoop import script below will give your desired outcome in the hive `person` table.

```
~]$ sqoop import \
--connect \
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lastdb \
--username=root \
--password=pass \
--query 'select * from person WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--hive-import \
--hive-table person \
--hive-database lastdb \
--target-dir  /user/hive/warehouse/person -m 1
```